# Looking for a better way do accomplish dataframe to dictionary by series

Tags: python

Here's a portion of what the Excel file looks like. Meant to include this the first time. Thanks for the help so far.

```
Name                Phone Number  Carrier
FirstName LastName1 3410142531    Alltel
FirstName LastName2 2437201754    AT&T  
FirstName LastName3 9247224091    Boost Mobile  
FirstName LastName4 6548310018    Cricket Wireless 
FirstName LastName5 8811620411    Project Fi
```

I am converting a list of names, phone numbers, and carriers to a dictionary for easy reference by other code. The idea is separate code will be able to call a name and access that person's phone number and carrier.

I got the output I need, but I'm wondering if there were an easier way I could have accomplished this task and get the same output. Though it's fairly concise, I'm interested in any module or built in of which I'm not aware. My python skills are beginner at best. I wrote this in Thorny with Python 3.6.4. Thanks!

```
#Imports
import pandas as pd
import math

# Assign spreadsheet filename to `file`
file = 'Phone_Numbers.xlsx'
# Load spreadsheets
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
# Load a sheet into a DataFrame by name: df1
df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1', header=0)
# Put the dataframe into a dictionary to start
phone_numbers = df1.to_dict(orient='records')

# Converts PhoneNumbers.xlsx to a dictionary
x=0
temp_dict = {}
for item in phone_numbers:
    temp_list = []
    for key in phone_numbers[x]:
        tempholder = phone_numbers[x][key]
        if (isinstance(tempholder, float) or isinstance(tempholder, int)) and math.isnan(tempholder) == False: # Checks to see if there is a blank and if the phone number comes up as a float
            # Converts any floats to string for use in later code
            tempholder = str(int(tempholder))
        else:
            pass
        temp_list.append(tempholder)    
    temp_dict[temp_list[0]] = temp_list[1:] # Makes the first item in the list the key and add the rest as values
    x += 1
print(temp_dict)
```

Here's the desired output:

```
{'FirstName LastName1': ['3410142531', 'Alltel'], 'FirstName LastName2': [2437201754, 'AT&T'], 'FirstName LastName3': [9247224091, 'Boost Mobile'], 'FirstName LastName4': [6548310018, 'Cricket Wireless'], 'FirstName LastName5': [8811620411, 'Project Fi']
```

Comment: can you show us what `phone_numbers` looks like (with just a subset of your data, for instance), and your desired output? In fact, just showing us the output of `df1.head()` would help a lot, as there might be something you can do directly from the dataframe.

Comment: As a first step to making it more concise, look into using `for x, item in enumerate(phone_numbers):` instead of `for item in phone_numbers:`, then you can get rid of `x=0` and `x+=1` (but there is probably a way to do away with the whole loop in general)

Comment: Awesome. The 'enumerate()' is nice. I added the input Excel snipit and output from the shell. Thanks for the tip and the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to iterate through the dataframe and use a dictionary comprehension:

```
temp_dict = {row['Name']:[row['Phone Number'], row['Carrier']] for _, row in df.iterrows()}
```

where `df` is your original dataframe (the result of `xl.parse('Sheet1', header=0)`). This basically iterates through all rows in your dataframe, creating a dictionary key for each Name, with Phone number and carrier as it's values (in a list), as you indicated in your output.

To make sure that your phone number is not null (as you did in your loop), you could add an `if` clause to your dict comprehension, such as this:

```
temp_dict = {row['Name']:[row['Phone Number'], row['Carrier']] 
    for _, row in df.iterrows() 
    if not math.isnan(row['Phone Number'])}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is a nice concise way to code it and is still easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.set_index('Name').T.to_dict('list')
```

should do the job ,Here df is your dataframe

Comment: This get it exactly as I need it. I'm still trying to understand what is happening though. Is this correct: The dataframe key is set to 'Name', then the dataframe is transposed to its side with the Names on top, and finally the 'to_dict('list')' makes a dictionary with the index as the key, and the remaining items as its values in a list. I have to visually what the outputs in order to understand. Thanks!

Comment: yes thats what it actually does . there are other ways obviously but this would be fastest I suppose